# ffmpeg kubernetes pod auto-scaling

Tags: kubernetes

first of all, I know how to scale out on Kube, so my question is :
is there any way to send a pod of FFmpeg, 4 commands which each one used to convert my video to a different format (ex. a 4k mkv video to mp4,x256,...).
obviously, I want to do 4 commands at the same time, which I mean every container in pod responsible for converting a video to a specific format.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more details. Where is the auto-scaling? I do not know how does the conversion works but I could help with k8s part.